# UK visa for non-EEA child of British mother

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa

My wife and I are living in Brazil and intend to immigrate to the UK. We are trying to figure out what is the best way to obtain a visa for our child so she can move with the family.

My wife is a British citizen (by descent - she was not born in the UK) and I have an EU passport. My wife's daughter (my stepdaughter) is seven years old and a national of Brazil, born prior to my wife acquiring citizenship. My wife has not lived in the UK for three years prior to acquiring citizenship, therefore the child cannot be registered as a British citizen. My wife has sole responsibility over the child.

I will start a job in the UK in January and have a signed contract for full-time employment with a company in London.

My wife's finances in Brazil do not meet the minimum financial requirement for a child visa. My finances in Brazil are plenty sufficient to meet this requirement. My salary in the UK will also be plenty sufficient.

What are the requirements for the child to enter and live with us in the UK? What is the correct type of visa? What are the supporting documents? Do we need to meet the financial requirements and if so can my own income as a stepfather be considered?

Finally, can the child enter with a visitor visa and apply in the UK?

Please note that I have read through the HO documentation multiple times, even started an application for a child of a settled person but it is all very confusing.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an EU passport, your stepdaughter should be able to enter the UK under the freedom of movement rules as your family member.  In UK terms, this means that she is entering under the implementing [Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/1052).  This is much less expensive than the "immigration rules" route and requires no proof of financial means, although your right to stay for longer than three months depends on being "qualified."  One way to be qualified is to be employed, so you are all set in that department.

As a Brazilian citizen, your stepdaughter does not need a visa, but she can apply for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).  If she does not apply for the permit, she can fly with you to the UK and present at the border the same evidence that she would have included in an EEA family permit application.

To underscore that she qualifies under the freedom of movement rules, here is Regulation 7(1):

> “Family member”
>
> 7.—(1) In these Regulations, “family member” means, in relation to a person (“A”)—
>
> (a) A’s spouse or civil partner;
>
> (b) A’s direct descendants, or the direct descendants of A’s spouse or civil partner who are either—
>
> (i) aged under 21; or
>
> (ii) dependants of A, or of A’s spouse or civil partner;
>
> (c) dependent direct relatives in A’s ascending line, or in that of A’s spouse or civil partner.

Your stepdaughter qualifies as your family member under 7(1)(b)(i) because she is the direct descendant of your spouse and she younger than 21 years.

> What are the supporting documents?

With regard to being "qualified," you will not need to show this when you apply for the EEA family permit nor at the border, because you haven't yet been in the UK for three months.  The basic documents you'll have to show are:

- proof of your EU nationality (passport or national ID card).
- proof of your stepdaughter's identity (passport).
- proof of your relationship (your marriage certificate and her birth certificate, showing your wife as her mother).  This will need to be authenticated.

> Do we need to meet the financial requirements ...

No.

> ... and if so can my own income as a step-father be considered?

Yes.  Another option would be to sponsor her under the immigration rules.  In that case, your wife would be the sponsor, but I believe your entire family income would be considered.  This is expensive, and if I were you I wouldn't do it; the main advantage would be to avoid the uncertainty around Brexit, but it seems unlikely that EU citizens in the UK will be kicked out.  It would be too unsustainable from a political perspective.

> Finally, can the child enter with a visitor Visa and apply in the UK?

For the freedom-of-movement route, yes, though it's better to claim the right of freedom of movement at the border rather than trying to enter as a visitor (for Brazilians, a visa is not necessary).  After arriving in the UK, in any event, you may want to get her a residence card; after Brexit she will need whatever document they're issuing as evidence of "settled status."

For the immigration rules route, no.  She must have a settlement visa before departing to the UK.

How does the UK's impending departure from the EU affect this?  There are basically two possible deadlines, depending on whether the UK leaves the EU with or without a "deal."  If there is a deal, your stepdaughter should be able to use the free movement regime to enter before the end of the "transition period" (currently expected to be [the end of 2020](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card) if I understand correctly).  If there is no deal, then there is a chance that she won't be able to use the free movement regime after Brexit (23:00 UK time, March 29, 2019).  But as is often said, "nothing is agreed until everything is agreed," so if you can move before the end of March, you should do so.

Comment: Thank you so much. This gives me a much easier path. One question: does the fact that my wife has legal sole responsibility over the child hinder in any way the EEA family permit?

Comment: @jfeferman perhaps, but I would think not.  The EU directive and the implementing regulations both make no mention of this.  (The directive also allows unrelated household members to benefit from derivative free movement though I'm not sure about the regulations, so that also suggests that a legal parental responsibility is not required.)  To avoid worrying about that, you might apply for the EEA family permit in Brazil.  This would avoid the stress of embarking for the UK with uncertainty about the legal interpretation.

Comment: @jfeferman I've added a paragraph about Brexit.

Comment: This is looking more like the easier route. I will be applying for the permit from Brazil. My daughter's ticket is scheduled for March 17. If she has the permit, do I need to travel with her in March or can she be accompanied by her British mother? Thank you so much!

Comment: @jfeferman you have to accompany or precede your stepdaughter for her to be able to use the EEA family permit.

Comment: Dear @phoog. Although my wife and I are married since 2013, we are only now getting a civil marriage. Since our application for the child will follow shortly the official marriage papers, I've read that the ECO will have grounds to suspect we have a marriage of convenience. I am prepared to submit with my application all the proof that we are indeed together since 2013. I will also submit my contract of employment, although I am not required to do so as I have not yet travelled to the UK. Do you believe this is the correct path to take when filing the application? Thank you!

Comment: @jfeferman If your (religious?) wedding in 2013 is valid in Brazilian law, it should also be valid in the UK. I suppose it isn't, though, given your plans. But your stepdaughter should at least *already* be eligible as a member of your household. The marriage of convenience question should be asked separately, but I will say here that you should be careful, because the definition in the 2016 regulations is very broad: "a marriage entered into for the purpose of using these Regulations...to circumvent [immigration criteria]."

Comment: we have not had an official wedding or any religious marriage. We are de facto married since we share a household and have children. Under Brazilian law this "stable union" is already sufficient to denote a real marriage even if no document was signed. The guidance for ECOs states evidence of the relationship "would include a marriage certificate, ..." which would be one type of evidence. Pictures, emails, etc. would also be evidence. Perhaps we could have our lawyer draft a memo explaining the Brazilian law in lieu of submitting a "civil marriage" certificate?

Comment: @jfeferman I suspect that a marriage of this sort would only count as a marriage if you have registered it with some civil authority (but it is certainly a "durable relationship").  If that is correct, it would mean that your stepdaughter is not formally a "family member."  The "member of the household" criterion should apply, however, making her an "extended family member," but showing that is a bit more involved than for a "family member."

Comment: Alas, we submitted an extensive EEA family permit application and were rejected on the grounds that I didn't provide proof of European nationality. I submitted both a notarised copy of my Portuguese passport and they scanned the original of my Portuguese identification card. Is this an error? Could there be any underlying reason they consider that I am not European? What would be the chances of my British wife and Brazilian daughter be barred at immigration if they try to obtain the EEA permit at the border, when entering the UK? Thank you!

Comment: @jfeferman that is definitely an error. We have seen more than one instance in which the form letter for rejection was not properly filled out, or not at all, before printing it.  If you post a new question with an image of the letter (with identifying information blacked out, of course), it should be possible to offer more advice, but in principle you should be able to get the refusal reversed by complaining. (To find that you are not an EU citizen in the face of the evidence, they have to acknowledge the evidence--your passport copy and ID card--and explain why it is insufficient.)

Comment: The chances of being barred at the border are probably low, but if I were you I would try to overturn this decision.  Improperly filled out form letters generally include language from a template document that is supposed to be deleted in cases where it does not apply.  It's possible that this happened here, or that for some reason the officer who evaluated the application never saw the evidence of your Portuguese nationality.

Comment: The refusal letter clearly states there is no right of appeal... our option would be to re-submit the application but it seems we have not enough time. At this time we are waiting for the passport to be returned and ready to make an emergency passport if that gets delayed. We'll then proceed with the planned request for EEA permit at the border.

Comment: @jfeferman for obvious mistakes like this, you should be able to get the decision reversed without a formal appeal.  If the letter was not.properly prepared, then it is entirely possible that the statement about appeal rights was also included in error.

Comment: After contracting a solicitor in the UK we did two things. We appealed the "non-appealable" refusal and were granted a hearing at the first tribunal. We submitted a new application largely based on the same grounds and pointing their error. This second application was granted! We will drop the appeal, not after spending money to contest the HO. All is well that ends well and your answer supported my conviction that we were in our right. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jfeferman congratulations. Good luck in the UK.